# The same data type for multiple variables in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a taxi booking agent.
My variables is: date, time, from and to. Two last ones is a street-address type. I need agent to catch both addresses from single phrase if it is. Like: "Going from Lelina str, 5 to Stadium str. 10"

While trainig i'm selecting "Lelina str, 5" as $from and "Stadium str. 10" as $to.

In another session i'm swaping those addresses ang getting problem here. ML trained that "Stadium str. 10" is a $from and not associates it with $to even in a required variable request.

I'll try to redesing single intent to followup intents to solve $from and $to variables in different ones, but it will add linearity to agents work.

Is there any solution to expand ML`s understangind for one data type but not bing to spacific variable?

Comment: UPD. The idea with followup is failed.
When system trained that "Lelina str, 5" is $from it is switching to from-followup intead saving this address as $to

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow what the problem is. Can you update your question to include screen shots of the Intents that illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are going through. Dialogflow still fails to handle two entities of the same type in a single intent.

Have you tried using `sys.address` system entities rather than defining your own. Even if you have your own have a common entity collection called `address` and use them with different parameter names.

One workaround I have tried and worked is to use `contexts` to chain the conversations and capture `$from` and `$to` in two intents. But this will not be viable when a user says the whole sentence like in the example.

Comment: I'm using address system entity. It's still bindint to specific ent name is there is from and to. Trying to solve via addresses as list. Will keep in touch

Answer (score 0):

My case is **solved** via using template mode instead of exmple.

https://miningbusinessdata.com/template-vs-example-mode-api-ai/